# Can't upload image using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with upload image with another input field.

This is my view

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn" id="upload_submit" name="upload_submit">
```

This is my controller

```
function do_upload()
{
    $file_paths = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/save_here/";
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    if($this->input->post('upload_submit')){
        if(isset($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
            $config['upload_path'] = $file_paths;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']     = '100';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('upload')){
                $error = array("status"=>"0",'error' => $this->upload->display_errors(),'upload_data'=>'');
            }else{
                $data = array("status"=>"1",'error'=>'','upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            }
       }
    }
}
```

My problem is I cannot upload the image or no image has been uploaded in `save_here` file.

Comment: avoid space in your directory name. Use something like save_here

Comment: @YadhuBabu still not working

Comment: any error message

Comment: @YadhuBabu just blank white screen

Comment: you have folder save_here in desktop?

Comment: @ImBS yes I create save_here in desktop and the path is correct

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization check my answer. change one line that's it

Comment: Just a tip instead of writing path like you have done you can use FCPATH like `FCPATH .  '/youruploadfolder';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try This. you have to initialize upload library with config

```
function do_upload()
{
    $file_paths = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/save_here/";
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    if($this->input->post('upload_submit')){
        if(isset($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
            $config['upload_path'] = $file_paths;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']     = '100';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '768';        

            // Change This line
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('upload')){
                    $error = array("status"=>"0",'error' => $this->upload->display_errors(),'upload_data'=>'');
                }else{
                    $data = array("status"=>"1",'error'=>'','upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                }
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your file path like this

> $file_paths = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\save_here\";